# socket通信のclose()について

Tags: python, network, socket

以下は、ネット上にあった他の方の書かれたソケット通信のサンプルプログラムです。
https://qiita.com/akakou/items/e9fbcfc0c69cc957152e

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

HOST = ''
PORT = 5000
ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1" # 自分に送信

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
# ブロードキャストする場合は、ADDRESSを
# ブロードキャスト用に設定して、以下のコメントを外す
# s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)

while True:
    msg = input("> ")
    # 送信
    s.sendto(msg.encode(), (ADDRESS, PORT))

s.close()
```

上記のコードでは、whileループの後にclose()の処理があります。
しかし、上記のようなコードの場合、whileループから抜け出すことがないので
closeが実行されることはなさそうな気がするのですが
closeを書く意味というのはあるのでしょうか？

close()を実行したほうが良い時というのはどのような時なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> close()を実行したほうが良い時というのはどのような時なのでしょうか？

このコードにおいては、意味はありません。
しかし、一般的には、socketなどのファイルディスクリプタは、使い終わったらcloseするべきです。